# RSA BadPaddingException when decrypting

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, javacard

I am encrypting some bytes of data On a java smart card using a public key I generated on a desktop app, but when I try to decrypt the data on my desktop I get the `BadPaddingException :  Data must start with zero`, I read that this might be caused by the use of a false private key to decrypt the data.

1. First, I generated a public/private key pair on a desktop app and loaded them on the smart card using the following code (being generated in `BigInteger` type, I converted them to hexadecimal, and from hexa decimal to a byte array):

   ```
   void keyGen(String ID)throws Exception{
       // where ID is the name of the user 
       KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
       kpg.initialize(512);
       KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
       this.pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) kp.getPublic();
       this.privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) kp.getPrivate();

       KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
       this.pub = fact.getKeySpec(kp.getPublic(), RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
       this.priv = fact.getKeySpec(kp.getPrivate(),  RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

       saveToFile(ID+".pub", pub.getModulus(),  pub.getPublicExponent());
       saveToFile(ID+".priv", priv.getModulus(),  priv.getPrivateExponent());

   }
   ```

here is the savetofile function:

```
    public void saveToFile(String fileName,  BigInteger mod, BigInteger exp) throws IOException {
          ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
          try {
            oout.writeObject(mod);
            oout.writeObject(exp);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException();
          } finally {
            oout.close();
          }
        }
```

This is the line used to store the public key on the smart card:

```
Main.sRmi.setPub(Crypto.hexStringToByteArray(Main.crypto.getPubMod().toString(16)), 
 toByteArray("0"+Main.crypto.getPubexp().toString(16)));
```

(The zero is added to the string because we cannot convert a string of odd hexadecimals into bytes)

2. Then I try to encrypt the data using that public key inside the card, and this is the function I'm using:

   ```
   private Cipher cipherRSA = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_PKCS1, false);
   private byte[] cipherText = new byte[64];

   public byte[] encrypt(byte[] clearText){

       cipherRSA.init(rsa_PublicKey, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
       cipherRSA.doFinal(clearText, (short)0,  (short)clearText.length,cipherText, (short)0 );
       return cipherText;
   }
   ```
3. Then I try to get this encrypted value on another desktop application, and decrypt it using the private key I'm reading from the file:

This is how I read the private key from the file:

```
public void init (String ID ) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception{

    Object o[] = openFile(ID+".pub");
    setPubMod((BigInteger) o[0]);
    setPubexp((BigInteger) o[1]);
    RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(this.pubMod, this.pubexp);
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
    o = openFile(ID+".priv");
    setPrivMod((BigInteger) o[0]);
    setPrivexp((BigInteger) o[1]);
    RSAPrivateKeySpec keySpec1 = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(this.privMod, this.privexp);
    fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) fact.generatePrivate(keySpec1);
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING"); 
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
}
```

After getting the private key in the `BigInteger` Variable, I decrypt using the following method:

```
public byte[] rsaDecrypt(byte[] data) throws Exception, BadPaddingException {

      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
      byte[] clearData = cipher.doFinal(data);
      return clearData;
    }
```

To sum it all up, I create a key pair in `BigInteger` Format, I save the `BigInteger` Variable into a `Serialized` array of two BigIntegers to be used by the other desktop App, then I convert them into Hexa `String`, then into an array of bytes which i put inside the smart card.

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with this procedure? Is it too much? Is there a better way to do so?

---

I think I know where the problem is, it's with the key stored inside the smart card, converting it the way I did obviously is not working, seeing how I read it from the card and printed it out and got a completely different result, so the question is now, how do I export successfully a public key created on java.crypto (in BigInteger) to the Smart card where public keys are stored in Bytes?

I found this:

Sets the public exponent value of the key. The plaintext data format is big-endian and right-aligned (the least significant bit is the least significant bit of last byte). Input exponent data is copied into the internal representation.

so how can I convert a big integer to this big-endian byte format?

Now I'm trying to set the public key, here is the code i'm executing for that:

```
public void setPub(byte[] expo,byte[] mod){
    rsa_PublicKey.clearKey();
    rsa_PublicKey.setExponent(expo, (short)0, (short)expo.length);
    rsa_PublicKey.setModulus(mod, (short)0, (short)mod.length);
}
```

where expo is a 65 byte array and mod is a 3 byte array generated by a key gen, but I'm getting this error :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.javacard.impl.NativeMethods.getCurrentContext()B
at com.sun.javacard.impl.NativeMethods.getCurrentContext(Native Method)
at com.sun.javacard.impl.PrivAccess.getCurrentAppID(PrivAccess.java:454)
at javacard.framework.CardRuntimeException.<init>(CardRuntimeException.java:46)
at javacard.security.CryptoException.<init>(DashoA10*..:25)
at com.sun.javacard.javax.smartcard.rmiclient.CardObjectFactory.throwIt(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javacard.javax.smartcard.rmiclient.CardObjectFactory.throwException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javacard.javax.smartcard.rmiclient.CardObjectFactory.getObject(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javacard.rmiclientlib.JCRemoteRefImpl.parseAPDU(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javacard.rmiclientlib.JCRemoteRefImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sid2.CompteurImpl_Stub.setPub(Unknown Source)
at sid2.ServerRmi.setPub(ServerRmi.java:27)
at AddCard$2.actionPerformed(AddCard.java:160)
```

and this is how the keys priv and pub are generated :

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(512);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    this.pubKey = kp.getPublic();
    this.privKey = kp.getPrivate();

    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    this.pub = fact.getKeySpec(kp.getPublic(), RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
    this.priv = fact.getKeySpec(kp.getPrivate(),  RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);
```

Comment: BigInteger is already in big-endian format according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/5878630/1096742

Comment: yeah thx, just googled that, but now i'm stuck again.

Answer (score 1):

"where expo is a 65 byte array and mod is a 3 byte array generated by a key gen, but i'm getting this error : ..."

Little wonder you get errors, the exponent is normally shorter than the modulus, which is always the same size as the key size. You are switching the modulus and the exponent around.

Comment: The only stacktrace in the question is for the  `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` which can't be caused by swapped exp and mod.

Comment: Hi @OlegEstekhin yeah, probably not the only mistake... I guess the RMI runtime got messed up while debugging this issue. One side updated, the other not, bye bye.